# How can I access the key under the tag/Parent Tag in Json File?

Tags: c#, json

```
{
  "MethodParameters": {
    "operation": [ "write", "click", "text" ],
    "stepDetail": "login",
    "welcome": "Hello Bob!"
  }
```

if I want to get the value of "stepDetail" under "MethodParameters".

I'm trying it like this:

```
public static JObject? jsconfig1 = ReadJson(@"DataFiles\jsconfig1.json".ToString()); 

public static string loginA = .SelectToken("MethodParameters").SelectToken("stepDetail").Value<string>();
```

but it does not work for me. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Removed Selenium and NUnit tags since this question doesn't involve them.

Answer (score 2):

Why cannot you do something like `{nameOfYourObject}.MethodParameters.stepDetail`?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't try this

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    json = File.ReadAllText(@"DataFiles\jsconfig1.json");

    var methodParameters = JObject.Parse(json)["MethodParameters"];
    string loginA = (string) methodParameters["stepDetail"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your json is saved in variables you can access to nested field.

```
var json = [YOUR JSON];
var nestedField = json["MethodParameters"]["stepDetail"]);
```

Comment: What is 'x' here?

Comment: @KhizarSohail sorry, I just modified.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your json to an object with `Newtonsoft.Json` and then work with it as any object.

This should be your class:

```
  public class MethodParameters
    {
        public List<string> operation { get; set; }
        public string stepDetail { get; set; }
        public string welcome { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public MethodParameters MethodParameters { get; set; }
    }
```